# Local table in Access tool opens slow for one particular user

Tags: ms-access

Since a few days, in various Access databases, opening a local (or remote) table has become very slow. Doesn't matter if that table only houses one single record, or 100.000.

This issue only applies to an account I use. If other users open the exact same database and the same table, it opens instantly. When I open that table, Access seems to freeze for a while (30+ seconds), before the table is opened.

An failed fix was to drop all registry information for Access for my account, didn't make a difference.

An working fix is creating a new blank database and import everything. Opening of tables is then normal again.

But, that would mean that I must do this for all Access database in our environment, and only to fix this issue which applies to me only.

Is this somehow explainable, and is there another way to solve this?

Comment: It could be a timeout for a (network) resource missing for that account.

Comment: Hi @Gustav, could this also affect the opening of a local table (so not a linked table)?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the cause.

We shut down a server a few days ago on which a few Access backend databases were located. That server was replaced and some local user interface Access databases were reconnected from the old to the new table locations.

But the old linked tables were not removed but renamed (e.g. tblData_OLD_SERVER).
Apparently, like @Gustav also hinted at, it is trying to reach that server even though I'm opening a local table.

I deleted all linked tables that were referring to that deleted server, and it's fine again...